# Can the standard Ruby logger be configured to flush after every message?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible for the standard Ruby logger (i.e. [`::Logger`](http://rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=C00000075&name=Logger)) to auto-flush after each write?

**Update:** I am setting a custom log formatter, as per [How to get timestamps in your ruby on rails logs](http://nopugs.com/2008/07/10/how-to-get-timestamps-in-your-ruby-on-rails-logs):

```
class Foo
  def initialize(params = {})
    @logger = Logger.new $stdout
    @logger.formatter = LogFormatter.new
    @logger.level = params.include?(:log) ? params[:log] : Logger::INFO
    # ...
  end

  class LogFormatter < Logger::Formatter
    def call(severity, time, progname, message)
      timestamp = time.iso8601
      log_msg = "#{timestamp}#{" [#{severity}]" if %w{ERROR WARN}.include? severity} "
      if message.is_a? Exception
        log_msg += "#{message.message}"
        log_msg += ": #{message.backtrace.join "\n#{timestamp}  "}" unless message.backtrace.blank?
      else
        log_msg += message
      end

      "#{log_msg}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to use the suggestion from [idlefingers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155328/idlefingers) as follows:

```
  def initialize(params = {})
    Rails.logger.auto_flushing = 1
    @logger = Logger.new $stdout
    @logger.formatter = LogFormatter.new
    @logger.level = params.include?(:log) ? params[:log] : Logger::INFO
  end
```

But no dice. Neither does `@logger.auto_flushing = 1` work for me. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** It turns out that ActiveSupport's [`::Logger`](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.1.2/doc/index.html?a=C00000047&name=Logger) simply wraps the standard Ruby `::Logger`. So my question turns out to be about Ruby and not Rails, after all.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Turns out it was just a matter of turning on the `sync` attribute of the underlying IO object:

```
  def initialize(params = {})
    $stdout.sync = true unless RAILS_ENV == 'production'
    @logger = Logger.new $stdout
    @logger.formatter = LogFormatter.new
    @logger.level = params.include?(:log) ? params[:log] : Logger::INFO
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

> Sets the “sync mode'' to true or false. When sync mode is true, all
> output is immediately flushed to the underlying operating system and
> is not buffered internally. Returns the new state. See also #fsync.

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/IO.html#method-i-sync

I had this issue where logs were buffered and only flushed every hour.

```
require 'logger'

STDOUT.sync = true
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT, level: :info)
logger.info "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set [ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.auto_flushing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/BufferedLogger.html#method-i-auto_flushing-3D) in your environment like so:

```
Rails.logger.auto_flushing = 1
```

This should make it flush after every message.

Comment: That's completely different to Rails logger (and your original question). I'm not sure off the top of my head how to do that with a custom log using stdout. You could use [io.sync = true](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000911) for file logging, but you'll have to google it for stdout logging.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought that Logger *was* the standard Rails logger. :-/

Comment: `ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger.auto_flushing` was [deprecated in Rails 3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#deprecations)